# How to join tables using linq and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join

In the code given below i want to join all the three table i get the data by joining the table but while displaying the data only the data of CK_Model is displayed. Please help

```
public List<CK_Model> GetDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var entities = new MobileStore2020Entities())
            {
                var details = from a in entities.CK_Model
                              join b in entities.CK_Brand
                              on a.BrandID equals b.BrandID
                              join c in entities.CK_Stock
                              on a.ModelID equals c.ModelID
                              select new 

                              {
                                  ModelID = a.ModelID,
                                  ModelName = a.ModelName
                              };
                return details.ToList();
```

Thank You.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to only display data from the table `entities.CK_Model`? Is that not what it's currently doing? if not, what is it currently doing?

Comment: No the data from CK_Model is get display but i want the data from all the three tables.

Comment: Well all you are doing in that statement above is getting the `ModelID` and the `ModelName` from the table `CK_Model`

Comment: Yes because other fields of other 2 tables are not accessible

Comment: If i removed **ModelID** and **ModelName** then i should get all the fields which match with the query but at that scenario also i get **ModelID** and **ModelName**

Comment: you are selecting a.ModelID and a.ModelName. in the same manner, you should be able to access b.Property and c.Property. However, for this you'll need another return type, because you do return properties of type CK_Model.

Comment: yes by using b.property1 and b.property2 i can access the other properties but cant return the proper values ya and my issue is of what type of return type should i use to return the value of join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to return data from all 3 tables by accessing them through your context. If you want to do this you have change your method's return type. For example create a new class with all 3 item types

```
public class DetailsItemType
{
     public CK_Model Model{ get; set; }
     public CK_Brand Brand { get; set; }
     public CK_Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your method's return type to DetailsItemType and you'll have something like the following

```
public List<DetailsItemType> GetDetails()
{
    using (var entities = new MobileStore2020Entities())
    {
        var details = from a in entities.CK_Model
                      join b in entities.CK_Brand
                      on a.BrandID equals b.BrandID
                      join c in entities.CK_Stock
                      on a.ModelID equals c.ModelID
                      select new DetailsItemType
                      {
                          Model= a,
                          Brand = b,
                          Stock = c
                      };
        return details.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now every time you call GetDetails() you can access all 3 tables. For example

```
var details = GetDetails();
var model = details.Model;
var brand = details.Brand;
var stock = details.Brand;
```